# Какие технологии использовать для работы с бд и сервером?

Tags: android

Приложение работает с локальной бд и удаленным сервером.
Каждый раз при запуске приложение обновляет бд(данные берет с сервера)
и на протяжении работы приложения все данные "тянутся" из локальной бд.

Были мысли использовать Firebase но я не уверен ибо данная бд предоставляет свою серверную часть.

Для работы с сервером думаю стоит использовать Retrofit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с сетью используйте Retrofit 2. Это наверно самый популярный и самый функциональный вариант. Для бд есть несколько вариантов. Если БД простая то можно посмотреть на cupboard, если сложная то используйте Requery - это очень гибкая и многофункциональная ORM

Comment: а что касаемо SQLite? или лучше не использовать?

Comment: Можно использовать чистый SQLite без ORM. Это будет самым быстрым решение. Но неудобно писать все самому. ORM  решают многие проблемы за вас, но уступают по скорости